# Sum of series in java

Tags: java

i'm trying to find the sum of series.If i get the number as "5" and the no of terms as "4"...Then the series goes like that (5*6*7)+(6*7*8)+(7*8*9)+(8*9*10)...likewise it has to do addition with respect to the no of terms.I tried this code but it gives the wrong output.Where i went wrong?

```
int num=5,n=4,i,j,res=0,sum=1;
int k=num+1;
for(i=1;i<=num-1;i++)
{
    k=k-1;
    sum=1;
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        sum=sum*k;
        k=k+1;
    }
}
res=res+sum;
System.out.println(res);
```

I got the output as 57120 but the correct output is 1770.

Comment: using `int` for such task is not a good idea

Comment: also shouln't the `res=res+sum` be inside the `for`?

Comment: This question has been answered already a lot of times. I'm not trying to scare you off, but you should look around the forum before asking those basic questions. Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

**YOUR CODE**

```
int num=5,n=4,i,j,res=0,sum=1;
int k=num+1;
for(i=1;i<=num-1;i++)
{
    k=k-1;
    sum=1;
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        sum=sum*k;
        k=k+1;
    }
}
res=res+sum;   // This line should be *inside* the previous curly bracket.
System.out.println(res);
```

The effect of setting `sum = 1;` is to remove the previous value of sum before adding the next term. This is only a good idea if you have **stored** the previous value is your result (res). So

`res = res + sum;`

should be within the outer **for** loop.

Since you are just multiplying by the next two numbers above k, you do not need an inner **for** loop. Just write

`sum += k * (k + 1) * (k + 2);`

Note the shorthand expressions:

`sum += ...`  means the same as `sum = sum +  ...`

`k++;`  means the same as  `k = k + 1;`

`k--;`   means the same as  `k = k - 1;`

Also, it is quicker for the computer to work out

`A < B + 1` (1 subtraction)

than it is to work out

`A <= B` (2 subtractions plus one logical OR).

So in logical expressions, we always write `A < B + 1` when we want `A <= B`.

Finally it is easier to read expressions with space between variables or characters than those without space, i.e. `a + 1`  is easier to read than `a+1`

**ALTERED CODE**

```
int num = 5,
    n = 4,
    k = n,
    i = k,
    res = 0;

for(i = k; i < k + n; i++) // Gives n terms, e.g. k = {num, num + 1, ..., num + n - 1}
{
    res += k * (k + 1) * (k + 2);
    k++;
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Why did you replace the while loop with the for loop? Earlier you have checked whether [ k < k+n ] in while loop and now you took an extra variable i to keep track that. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I'm deferring to the student's original code and removing most of the primitive errors for now. I don't want to go into the *while* v *for* argument for now - though it is better done with a *while* loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Java 8 streams for this problem.

For example:

```
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.range;

...

int num = 5, n = 4;
int sum1 = range(0, n).map(l -> range(num + l, num + l + 3).reduce(1, (a, r) -> a * r)).sum();
System.out.println(sum1);
```

This prints out:

```
1770
```

Explanation:

```
range(0, n) // ensures that the sum operation is executed `n` times.
.map(l -> range(num + l, num + l + 3) // generates sequences of 3 numbers starting from `num` increased by `l`
.reduce(1, (a, r) -> a * r) // calculates the product of the sequences of 3 numbers
.sum() // sums the product of all three numbers
```

Comment: You are taking the student too far to fast, I feel. . . .

Comment: @Trunk I think you are right. But perhaps one day he / she will appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah - about 1 semester down the road !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int num = 5;
int sum = 0;
int n = 4;
for(int i = 0; i<n ;i++) {
  int ele = 1;
  for (int k = num + i; k < num + i + n - 1; k++) {
     ele *= k;
  }
  sum += ele;
 }
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: it works...But it fails for the negative input and if i give num=1 and n=4 it prints the wrong output.